# I am Creating pie chart using Chartjs 2.6.0. I want to show label on Slices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I am using Chartjs(V2.6.0) pie chart and I'd like to show Labels on pie Chart slices.
Please find mycode below

HTML Canvas:

```
<canvas id="pieChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
```

My Chart Option Object Is

```
var pieOptions = {
        elements: {
            arc: {
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 10,
            bottom: 0
        }
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
       labels: {
                boxWidth: 12
            }
    }
};
```

My Chart Code:

```
[![new Chart($("#pieChart"), {
                    type: 'pie',
//                    type: 'doughnut',
                    data: {
                        labels: \['4HR', 'Ba-D', 'Cx-D', 'CID'\],
                        datasets: \[
                            {
                                data: \[12,43,67,98\]
                            }
                        \]
                    },
                    options: pieOptions
                });][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChartPieceLabel

Try the [link](https://github.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js) to download

Also, if you want to see a demo of how they look, you can try the following [link](https://emn178.github.io/Chart.PieceLabel.js/samples/demo/)

Comment: It worked for me, But using this Either I can show the label or value.
I want to display -  Label(value). is there any option for this
My code:

pieceLabel: {
     mode: 'label',
     fontColor: '#000',
     position: 'outside'
  }

Comment: I am sure there must be a way but honestly you wouldn't want to clutter your graphics with that kind of detailed information. Your legend should help you. Meanwhile I'll look out for a solution if I can find.